# GAM model interpretation

Tags: r, p-value, generalized-additive-model, mgcv

I am trying to understand if my model treat `ndvi` like the `coordinates` (i.e. does it fit a spline to the relationship between `ndvi` and the `outcome`) or fit a spline to `longitude` and `latitude`, and a simple linear term for `ndvi`? I don’t know if the p-value indicates that adding the `ndvi` term to the model significantly improves the fit, or whether this is a p-value for a simple linear association.

````r
> library(mgcv)
>
> summary.gam(m2)
> 
> Family: binomial  Link function: logit 
> 
> Formula: Outcome ~ lo(Xcoord, Ycoord, ndvi, span = 0.95)
> 
> Parametric coefficients:
>                                                Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)  
> (Intercept)                                   -2.870e+02  2.213e+02  -1.297   0.1947  
> lo(Xcoord, Ycoord, ndvi, span = 0.95)Xcoord  1.496e-05  3.649e-05   0.410   0.6818  
> lo(Xcoord, Ycoord, ndvi, span = 0.95)Ycoord  3.559e-05  2.863e-05   1.243   0.2138  
> lo(Xcoord, Ycoord, ndvi, span = 0.95)ndvi  1.906e+00  7.801e-01   2.444   0.0145 *
> 
> Signif. codes:  0 *** 0.001 ** 0.01 * 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
>
>
> R-sq.(adj) =  0.00111   Deviance explained = 0.26%
> UBRE = -0.3706  Scale est. = 1         n = 5254                                              
>
> anova.gam(m2)
> Family: binomial 
> Link function: logit 

> Formula:
> Outcome ~ lo(Xcoord, Ycoord, ndvi75, span = 0.95)

> Parametric Terms:
>                                        df Chi.sq p-value
>
> lo(Xcoord, Ycoord, ndvi, span = 0.95)  1  5.971  0.0145

```
````

Comment: You seem to be using *mgcv* but with the LOESS smooth type (`lo()`) which isn't advisable as `lo()` comes from the *gam* package.

Answer (score 0):

What I mean by my comment

> You seem to be using *mgcv* but with the LOESS smooth type (`lo()`) which isn't advisable as `lo()` comes from the *gam* package.

is that your model isn't actually fitting any splines (loess smooths) at all; you're getting 4 parametric coefficients estimated and that's it.

If you want a 3d smooth of `Xcoord`, `Ycoord`, and `ndvi` you could do:

```r
Outcome ~ te(Xcoord, Ycoord, ndvi)
```

or

```r
Outcome ~ te(Xcoord, Ycoord, ndvi, bs = c("tp", "cr"), d = c(2,1))
```

The first model would assume anisotropy in the smooths, so the wiggliness in `Xcoord` could be different to the wiggliness in `Ycoord`. The second model fits a 2d spatial smooth with a single smoothness parameter where there is an assumption of isotropy (same degree of wiggliness in the X and Y directions).

Comment: Thanks for the precious information, Gavin Simpson. I 
want to smooth the relationship between X and the outcome, and Y and the outcome - to run a 2D smooth, with the linear effect of NDVI added in. Does the second model do it?

Comment: If you want a *model* with a smooth interaction between `x` and `y` plus a linear effect of `ndvi` thenstart with something like: `~ te(x, y) + ndvi` If you are happy to not assume the effect of `ndvi` is linear then `~ te(x, y) + s(ndvi)` would get you the non-linear/smooth effect of `ndvi` plus the smooth interaction of `x` and `y`.